# git log output gets directly dumped, without going through a pager

Tags: git, wsl-2

[image]

As the GIF above shows, running `git log` in my WSL2 Ubuntu suddenly became noninteractive. It would show all the logs at once (while the Windows counterpart seemed to be working fine). `git` has already been updated to the latest version, and this behavior is also present when running WSL2 by itself, i.e., not using the Windows Terminal app. Any ideas on what caused the issue? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I guess pager should fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the doc for [`git config core.pager`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corepager) (from `git help config`) :

> **core.pager**
>
> Text viewer for use by Git commands (e.g., less). The value is meant to be interpreted by the shell. The order of preference is the `$GIT_PAGER` environment variable, then `core.pager` configuration, then `$PAGER`, and then the default chosen at compile time (usually `less`).

check the values of :

```
echo $GIT_PAGER
git config core.pager
echo $PAGER
```

If the pager is indeed `less`, confirm that `less` is installed (this is very probably the case: `less --version`), and then check the environment variables that affect `LESS` :

```
env | grep LESS
```

it could be that some of these options turn off the paging of `less`.

Finally, if all the values above look like usual values, check if your terminal and tty report correct values (`echo $TERM`, I just fished `stty size` from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215584/whats-the-name-of-the-environment-variable-with-current-terminal-width), etc ...).

Answer (score 4):

It seems no pager is working on your Ubuntu. Try `git -c core.pager=more log` or  `git -c core.pager=less log`. It could still not work if `more` or `less` is not available. If it works, you can set a global option by

```
git config --global core.pager less
# or "more", depending on which takes effect
```

Besides, you can disable the pager temporarily by `git --no-pager log`.

Answer (score 0):

`git log` is supposed to show a list of all the commits to the repository, so it's working as intended [see documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)? Maybe you never noticed it before because your repo was smaller? And now you've got so many commits its freezing? Is it only temporary? (your GIF looks like its piping through a tool like less)

If you don't want this, use some command-line arguments to refine what you are doing.

`git log -n 1`

Shows only the most recent commit. `-n 2` shows the two most recent, and so on...

Many of the windows git tools are wrappers for git, so maybe they do extra stuff which would explain differences in behaviour that you've seen

Comment: the OP is suprised by the fact that his pager doesn't kick in. The title of the question could be reworked.

Comment: @LeGEC thanks for that clarification! Now the title has been updated, my answer makes less sense